# Backward vs Forward Architecture

Tags: architecture

Does the title definitions means something?

I have here some notes I took a while ago and the only thing I wrote is

forward == simpler

backward == harder to grow

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

It's not well-established terminology, as far as I know. But what were you taking notes of or for? It may be easier to understand given some context.

Perhaps the subject was [forward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility) (which makes things easier if you have it but require forethought and some luck) vs. [backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) (which often leads to ugly hacks but is usually what you have to settle for even if you thought you had forward compatibility).

Comment: Nope, it was an introductory OO course. I think is more in the line of iterations vs BDUF, but I'm not sure..